# How to create two different chart with drilldown in highchart

Tags: highcharts, linechart, react-highcharts, column-chart, drilldown-highcharts-map

Initially I want to show line chart
And show column chart after drill down specific point

**Expected Result:**

Before Drill down
[image]

After Drill down
[image]

```
For Answer check my js field link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hx6scbuy/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, on the official [website of Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/column-drilldown) you have a practically ready solution, all you need to do is change the type of the main series to linear (`type: 'line'`) and for the drilldown series to column (`type: 'column'`).

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pbjkmtd/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown

Comment: All this works just fine until you want to toggle between a bar and column chart. Apparently, a bar chart is just an inverted column chart and there's no way to programmatically change the inverted property. I'm guessing the only way to get it to work is to destroy and rebuild the chart programmatically which means not actually using the built-in drilldown module.